# How to set Navigational properties through App event receiver in SP2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, client-object-model, apps-development

I am trying to set the navigational properties in SP2013 autohosted app. I am doing this at App installed receiver. I have  written below code for that, which is failing with error message:

**- The remote event receiver callout failed. Details: The server was
   unable to process the request due to an internal error. For more
   information about the error, either turn on
   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute
   or from the configuration behavior) on the server in order to send
   the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as
   per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the
   server trace logs.**

Below is the code I am using:

public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();

```
        using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateAppEventClientContext(properties, false))
        {
            if (clientContext != null)
            {
                clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                if (properties.EventType == SPRemoteEventType.AppInstalled)
                {

                    clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();



                    try
                    {
                        WebNavigationSettings webNavigationSetting = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.Navigation.WebNavigationSettings(clientContext, clientContext.Web);
                        var currentNavigation = webNavigationSetting.CurrentNavigation;
                        var globalNavigation = webNavigationSetting.GlobalNavigation;

                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                        currentNavigation.Source = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.Navigation.StandardNavigationSource.PortalProvider;

                        clientContext.Web.Update();
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void ProcessOneWayEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
    {
        // This method is not used by app events
    }
```

Any help would be really appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My app was running on **Azure**. In my case the libraries

**Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.dll**

**Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll**

ware not uploaded to the Azure. After uploading them manually via FTP manager, the issue was resolved

Brian's Answer is also relevant. You do need to update your publishing web in order to make changes

```
    TaxonomySession taxSession = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(clientContext)
    webNavigationSetting.Update(taxSession);
```

You do not need to update the current Web because you did not make any changes to it:

```
    clientContext.Web.Update(); // you do not need this in the current example
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>`clientContext.Web.Update();`</strike>

```
TaxonomySession taxSession = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(clientContext)
webNavigationSetting.Update(taxSession);
```

Comment: Would you please add a few words of explanation to your answer? Just posting some code does not help much with understanding what the issue and the solution is.